# Scenario selecting with IF for financial modeling

Tags: microsoft-excel, finance

For forecasting revenue, I need to take the average revenue growth of the last three years in percentage. Then add 5% for the Best Case scenario.

Here is the formula used:

=(((((((E5-D5)/D5)*100) + (((D5-C5)/C5)*100) + (((C5-B5)/B5)*100)/3)+5)+100)/100)*E5

[Excel file link.](https://techcosec-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/digitalsplendid_techcosec_onmicrosoft_com/Edu0YCa6ra1NqBhqeRfIaW0B3v9_6ISZf6eJ1CoLOcArtw?e=zru7g2)

Any clue why formula giving inflated forecasted revenue appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I can't replicate the error. The formula in D1 (`=IF(D1 = "Best Case", bestcase_)`) with your bestcase_ being in I17 is working correctly.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio Revised my query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `Reddy Lutonadio` has said, there's nothing in that formula that should not work.

In fact, the only likely seeming possible way for such a simple, straightforward formula to fail would be if the Named Range did not actually exist.

In your problem statement, you state you created `bestprice_` and then this formula which then did not work. The formula uses a Named Range called `bestcase_` which, as you can see differs from the Named Range you state you created. Since you would appear to be stepping through your actions so we have a clear picture of how you ended up with a failing formula, one has to wonder if, in fact, the Named Range `bestcase_` has not, in fact, been created and so the formula has no idea what you wish returned to the cell.

That's a very simplistic possibility, but due to the short and straightforward nature of your formula which is not working, it seems there's a very good chance it's actually what happened.

If so, rename the Named Range and all should be good. If not, well, nothing else occurs to me, either.

No matter how sure you are it is not so, it takes just a moment to check, so why not? I would have myself if the file link had allowed it, but it does not so it must fall to you.

Comment: Sorry, Indeed, I messed up with bestprice_ and bestcase_. On rechecking, the formula indeed working. Should I delete this thread. My apology for the inconvenience.

Comment: Revised my query.